# How to make every pages in Group tree has the same page number in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I'm really struggling with this. I really need help.

So, the problem is I have 6 items in Group tree as you can see here.
[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ageXv.png)
 Every items use main report which has 4 subreports in it like this
[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOYCC.png)
the result i want is every subreport in each items of group tree will have the same page number and total page number is 6

Ex.
First Item - Page 1/6 , Page 1/6 , Page 1/6, Page 1/6
Second Item - Page 2/6 , Page 2/6 , Page 2/6, Page 2/6
and so on.

but now it's just show me total page is 24 and page number is just going from 1 to 24 as usual.

Comment: May you use a counter controlled by your own? In main report, create a running total field that count on change of group. Then pass it to the subreports as a parameter (using subreport link).

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the total page count from the main report to the subreport via a shared variable.

You should also be able to suppress the extra pagenofms in the main report when pagenumber > totalpagecount

Comment: can you suggest me a link, blog or the way to do it coz I'm really new to crystal report and I'm not good with crystal report syntax yet.